# PHP7 return type to JSON

Tags: php, php-7

PHP 7 has a new feature which is a return type declaration.

We can return type a 'string' like:

```
function myFunction ($a) : string  { }
```

We can also return type an 'array' like:

```
function myFunction ($a) : array  { }
```

But how can we declare a 'JSON' type of response?

Comment: JSON isn't a datatype. It's a structured string. So if your function returns JSON, you're returning a string, like a serialized object would also be.

Comment: You could write a custom class that just wraps a string and performs some validation on it, but that's about as close as you're going to get. If you implemented `__toString` on it as well then your calling code shouldn't even need to know the difference.

Comment: Thanks guys! sorry my bad, yeah +1 for @iainn  thats a good idea

Answer (score 22, accepted):

JSON isn't a native datatype in PHP,  it's a structured string. So if your function returns JSON, you're returning a string.

So `function myFunction ($a) : string  { }` would be correct.

If you want to describe the return further you should be using docs.

```
/**
 * @return string $jsonString The returned string contains JSON
 */
function myFunction ($a) : string  { }
```

The same also goes for serialized objects in PHP. A serialized object is a structured string.

Answer (score 0):

I like @KhorneHoly answer. However, you might consider a better function name (`myFunction` is just a dummy name, isn't it?):

```
function getJson($a) : string { }
```

This makes it obvious that returned string is actually JSON (with no need to use PHPDocs).

Answer (score -1):

```php
class PropertyNormalizer
{
    /**
     * @param Object $doc
     * @return NormalisedProperty
     */
    public function normalize(Object $doc): Object
    {
        $property = new NormalisedProperty($doc);
        // ... 
        return $property;
    }
}
```