# what return type to declare when returning respone()->json()

Tags: json, laravel, php-7

I declared the return type as a string and got the headers. i just want to get the json. how to remove headers when return json and return type is string.

this is what i got

[image]

from this

[image]

Comment: take a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/52183041/6945325

Answer (score 3):

By typehinting the return type as `string`, you're causing PHP to type coerce the return type of `response()->json()`, which is `\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse`, to a string. This will cause it to invoke the `__toString()` method

which looks like this:

```
public function __toString()
{
    return
        sprintf('HTTP/%s %s %s', $this->version, $this->statusCode, $this->statusText)."\r\n".
        $this->headers."\r\n".
        $this->getContent();
}
```

What I suggest is to typehint the return type as `\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse` instead of `string` as that's what you're returning. If you *really* want to return a `string` then you could do `return response()->json()->getContent();` however you want the headers (since you're return json, the `Content-Type` header becomes important)

Answer (score 0):

I  misunderstand that why you need to declare return type as string. But, It actually you want to response data as json.

Comment: for php7 return type. and because json is a string

Comment: $data = DB::table('your_table')->get(); return Response::json(['data' => $data],201);

Comment: headers still there

Comment: i get it. i can use json_encode instead of response()->json() but i shouldnt do it because im working on an api